# How do I preserve a hamburger menu when linking from a contentpage?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I've been using the `MasterPageDetail` approach in creating a hamburger menu for my Xamarin Forms app.  The menu itself works fine as taken from the Xamarin documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/.  What I noticed was that if I create a simple link to a page in one of my views, the hamburger menu and it's icon are replaced with a back button.

What I would like to know is how to create a link in a content page that will preseve my hamburger menu instead of showing a back button.  Any link you click from the `MasterPage` takes you to the corrosponding view but you can still see the hamburger menu, if you click a link within one of the pages however you are taken to the page but with a back button instead.  It's causing a very confusing navigational experience for my users.

The following code demonstrates how the manu is created in the hamburger menu just now.

```
public partial class MasterPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListView ListView { get { return listView; } }
        public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //var master = new MasterPage();
            var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem>();

            masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Dashboard",
                IconSource = "dashboard-icon-24.png",
                TargetType = typeof(Dashboard)
            });            
            listView.ItemsSource = masterPageItems;
}
```

So that works perfectly, you can navigate around and the hamburger menu is there all the time.

Within my view called 'dashboard' I added some link to hope to those same pages that are in my hamburger menu, I did so int he following way:

```
 <Button Text="Information" Clicked="informationClick" />
```

The code for this is as follows:

```
private void informationClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Information());
    }
```

When you click on this link however you lose the hambuger menu and it's repalced with the back button instead.  I want to preserve the hamburger menu, does anyone know how I can do this from my content page?

Comment: You're pushing a new screen onto the Navigation Stack and the user needs to have a way to move back. I don't think moving away from that pattern works wonders for the usability of your app. You could push the information screen modally, but that will still not have the hamburger menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must replace the "Detail" property of your MasterDetail page with a new NavigationPage containing the page you are linking.

Something like that:

```
(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContactsPage());
```

This is not really clean but it makes the idea.